# how to create an adjacency matrix with time overlaps?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr, networkx

Consider this simple example

```
#python bros
pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,1,2,3],
                       'time_in' : [0,30,1,5],
                       'time_out' : [2,35,3,6]})
Out[66]: 
   id  time_in  time_out
0   1        0         2
1   1       30        35
2   2        1         3
3   3        5         6


#R bros
dplyr::data_frame(id = c(1,1,2,3),
                  time_in = c(0,30,1,5),
                  time_out = c(2,35,3,6))
```

Here, the interpretation is pretty simple.

Individual `1` stays on a given place between time `0` and time `2`. Individual `2` stays there between time `1` and time `3`. Therefore, individual `2` met  individual `1` and is connected to it in my network.

That is, nodes of my networks are the `id`, and there is an edge between two nodes if their `[time_in, time_out]` interval overlap.

Is there an efficient way to generate the `adjacency matrix` or the `edge list` out of this input data so that I can use it in a network package such as `networkx`? My real dataset is way bigger than that.

Thanks!

Comment: both. I dont mind using either one. This looks like a non-standard problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a possible solution to make the adjacency matrix. The idea is to compare every time slot against each other and then reduce the comparison by vertex groups.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1, 1, 2, 3],
                   'time_in' : [0, 30, 1, 5],
                   'time_out' : [2, 35, 3, 6]})
# Sort so equal ids are together
df.sort_values('id', inplace=True)
# Get data arrays
ids = df.id.values
t_in = df.time_in.values
t_out = df.time_out.values
# Graph vertices
vertices = np.unique(ids)
# Find time slot overlaps
overlaps = (t_in[:, np.newaxis] <= t_out) & (t_out[:, np.newaxis] >= t_in)
# Find vertex group slices
reduce_idx = np.concatenate([[0], np.where(np.diff(ids) != 0)[0] + 1])
# Reduce by vertex groups to make adjacency matrix
connect = np.logical_or.reduceat(overlaps, reduce_idx, axis=1)
connect = np.logical_or.reduceat(connect, reduce_idx, axis=0)
# Clear diagonal if you want to remove self-connection
i = np.arange(len(vertices))
connect[i, i] = False
# Adjacency matrix as data frame
graph_df = pd.DataFrame(connect, index=vertices, columns=vertices)
print(graph_df)
```

Output:

```
       1      2      3
1  False   True  False
2   True  False  False
3  False  False  False
```

Comment: nice but I wonder how does that scale with many rows. cant we use pandas instead of raw numpy here?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ Maybe, although I'm not sure how (maybe someone else can work it out). I mean you can group by `id` obviously, but I don't know about the rest. There may be other possible algorithms too depending on the data. For example, if time slots are always integer you could represent the presence of each vertex as a bool array and operate with those, although I'm not sure under what conditions that would be better or worse.

Comment: thanks. It may also be that getting the `edge list` is easier that getting the `adjacency matrix`